Is there any design pattern or way in Javascript that can be used to display some of the fields in nested JSON array
Below is the nested array of objects that needs to be displayed as a table. Currently, map is used to loop through items to return another array of all the elements required to display.
    {
  "employees": {
    "employee": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Cruise",
        "colleagues": [
          {
            "id": "11",
            "firstName": "Cody",
            "lastName": "Jr"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "firstName": "Maria",
            "lastName": "Sharapova"
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "firstName": "Robert",
            "lastName": "Downey Jr."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Sharapova",
        "colleagues": [
          {
            "id": "5",
            "firstName": "Cody",
            "lastName": "Jr"
          },
          {
            "id": "6",
            "firstName": "Maria",
            "lastName": "Sharapova"
          },
          {
            "id": "7",
            "firstName": "Robert",
            "lastName": "Downey Jr."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Downey Jr.",
        "colleagues": [
          {
            "id": "8",
            "firstName": "Cody",
            "lastName": "Jr"
          },
          {
            "id": "9",
            "firstName": "Maria",
            "lastName": "Sharapova"
          },
          {
            "id": "10",
            "firstName": "Robert",
            "lastName": "Downey Jr."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Is there any design pattern or way in Javascript that can be  used to display some of the fields in this nested JSON array instead of another regular JS array object to display the below array.
"employees": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Cruise",
        "colleague_id": "11",
        "colleague_first_name": "Cody",
        "colleague_last_name": "Jr"
      } ...
    ]


How is that second format expected to work for the other colleague entities...?

Same as the given object inside employees

@Rudra but there is one employee which has multiple colleagues. There is no way to provide the data for multiple colleagues when the employee object only has a single colleague_id

Try to use flatMap to get it done.
It will returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level.
Example:


let data = {
  "employees": {
    "employee": [{
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Cruise",
        "colleagues": [{
            "id": "11",
            "firstName": "Cody",
            "lastName": "Jr"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "firstName": "Maria",
            "lastName": "Sharapova"
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "firstName": "Robert",
            "lastName": "Downey Jr."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Sharapova",
        "colleagues": [{
            "id": "5",
            "firstName": "Cody",
            "lastName": "Jr"
          },
          {
            "id": "6",
            "firstName": "Maria",
            "lastName": "Sharapova"
          },
          {
            "id": "7",
            "firstName": "Robert",
            "lastName": "Downey Jr."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Downey Jr.",
        "colleagues": [{
            "id": "8",
            "firstName": "Cody",
            "lastName": "Jr"
          },
          {
            "id": "9",
            "firstName": "Maria",
            "lastName": "Sharapova"
          },
          {
            "id": "10",
            "firstName": "Robert",
            "lastName": "Downey Jr."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

data.employees = data.employees.employee.flatMap(({
  colleagues,
  ...emp
}) => {
  return colleagues.flatMap((c) => ({ 
    ...emp,
    colleague_id: c.id,
    colleague_first_name: c.firstName,
    colleague_last_name: c.lastName
  }))
});

console.log(data);



